P2tr transaction with musig2 rust
I'm trying to build a p2tr that spends a 2-2 musig aggregated address. My process is as follow:

Create SecretKey, PublicKey pair from each party
Aggregate those 2 public keys
Create and publish a transaction to send deposit money to that aggregated address (Tx0)
Using musig2 to aggregated a valid signature to spend that address
Create a p2tr transaction to spend that address with the valid signature (Tx1)

Every time I publish Tx1 to the blocktream, it always returns the Invalid Schnoor Signature error.
In the context of creating the keypair in step 1, I used this code :
 let owner_keypair = Keypair::new(&secp, &mut rand::thread_rng());
 let owner_seckey = SecretKey::from_keypair(&owner_keypair);
 let owner_pubkey = PublicKey::from_keypair(&owner_keypair);

Do we need to tweak these keys before the aggregation step, since I know that the valid pubkey for BIP340 is an even-y-coordinate pubkey.
FYI I have this function to create the aggregated keys :
pub fn aggregate_pubkeys(
    owner_pubkey: PublicKey,
    se_pubkey: PublicKey,
) -> (PublicKey, PublicKey, Address, KeyAggContext) {
    let secp = Secp256k1::new();
    let mut pubkeys: Vec<PublicKey> = vec![];
    pubkeys.push(owner_pubkey);
    pubkeys.push(se_pubkey);
    let key_agg_ctx_tw = KeyAggContext::new(pubkeys.clone())
        .unwrap()
        .with_unspendable_taproot_tweak()
        .unwrap();

    let aggregated_pubkey: PublicKey = key_agg_ctx_tw.aggregated_pubkey_untweaked();
    let aggregated_pubkey_tw: PublicKey = key_agg_ctx_tw.aggregated_pubkey();

    let aggregated_address = Address::p2tr(
        &secp,
        aggregated_pubkey.x_only_public_key().0,
        None,
        Network::Testnet,
    );

    (
        aggregated_pubkey,
        aggregated_pubkey_tw,
        aggregated_address,
        key_agg_ctx_tw,
    )
}

The aggregated_pubkey is used to create the scriptpubkey for Tx0 and aggregated_pubkey_tw is used for the musig2 process.
Thank you a lot for helping me.

Having the same issue, did you ever solve this?
